# Function that will accept a list object as an argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a function that will accept a list object as an argument. The function will compute another list object containing the remainders of all elements in the list argument when divided by 2. The function will save the two list objects(list argument and the new list object) to a file `obj.txt`.

For example, if the list argument is [10,11,12,13,14], the new list object will be [0,1,0,1,0]. the content of the fill will look like:

```
10,0 
11,1 
12,0 
13,1 
14,0
```

I tried writing the code below but got stuck, kindly help please:

```
def firstFunction(myF):
   for i in myF:
       print(i)
numbers = [10,11,12,13,14]
firstFunction(numbers)
for c in numbers:
   newNumber = c%2
   print(newNumber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def func(numbers):
    with open("obj.txt", "w") as f:
        for n in numbers:
            print(n, n%2, sep=',' file=f)

# usage:
func(range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def firstFunction(numberList):
    remainderlist = []
    for i in numberList:
        remainderlist.append(i%2)
    return remainderlist

numbers = [10,11,12,13,14]
remainders = firstFunction(numbers)

with open("obj.txt", "w") as f:
    for num in remainders:
        f.write("{}\n".format(str(num)))
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback but when i run the code it returns error... "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found".

Comment: @KennethAjagba My bad, I edited the code, try now

Comment: def firstFunction(numberList):
    remainderlist = []
    for i in numberList:
        remainderlist.append(i%2)
    return returnlist

numbers = [10,11,12,13,14]
def func(numbers):
    with open("obj.txt", "w") as f:
        for n in numbers:
            print(n, n%2, sep=',', file=f)

func(range(10))

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but it should be `return remainderlist`not `return returnlist`

Comment: Oh my bad. Actually corrected it. The correct form is  "return remainderList". Thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not replacing the function with a simple listcomp?

```
result = [i%2 for i in numbers]

with open('obj.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a, b in zip(numbers, result):
        f.write(f'{a},{b}\n')
```